# SAPUI5-Which method to call once a view is displayed everytime?

Tags: sapui5

I want to do some logic before a view is displayed every time.I cannot go with before rendering method since it is called only once when the view is created and shown for the first-time.Pls help.Any ideas?

Comment: The current accepted answer misleadingly suggests `onBefore/AfterRendering` as a solution which is an **anti-pattern** in this case (It won't work without calling `invalidate()` every time, plus, `invalidate()` is not even a public method). See [_`onBeforeRendering` is not called every time_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55082731/5846045).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why do you think the before rendering method of a control is called only once? Do you have any sample code?

I've created a quick a dirty example on jsbin (http://jsbin.com/qikokayo/1/edit?html,output) for you to have a look at. It clearly shows that `onInit` is called once but `onBeforeRendering` is called every time...

Also see this snippet [from the OpenUI5 SDK](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/121b8e6337d147af9819129e428f1f75.html#loio121b8e6337d147af9819129e428f1f75__section_EF7E041513E34F3FAB23FCF5F5BB1F8B) which explains:

> ### Lifecycle Hooks
>
> `onInit()` - Called when a View is instantiated and its controls (if
>   available) are already created. Can be used to modify the View before
>   it is displayed to bind event handlers and do other one-time
>   initialization.
>
> `onExit()` - Called when the View is destroyed. Use this one to free
>   resources and finalize activities.
>
> `onAfterRendering()` - Called when the View has been rendered (therefore
>   its HTML is part of the document). Post-rendering manipulations of the
>   HTML can be done here. This hook is the same one that SAPUI5 controls
>   get after being rendered.
>
> `onBeforeRendering()` - Is invoked before the Controller's View is
>   re-rendered. You would use onInit() in the case that the hook shall be
>   invoked only before the first rendering.
>
> For Controllers without a View, no lifecycle hooks will be called.

Comment: Hi,
   I am using mvc based split app.So when you first add a detail page the before rendering method is called.But when we call the detail page next time by toDetail,then the method is not called.I've tried.

Comment: the word "re-rendered" in the onBeforeRendering definition is confusing me...it seems to be invoked before the first rendering of the view as well as upon re-renderings, not only when the view is re-rendered. The jsbin shows onBeforeRendering getting called on first page load: http://jsbin.com/qikokayo/1/edit ... Am I missing something?

Comment: _> I've created a quick [example on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qikokayo/1/edit?html,output) [...] It clearly shows that `onBeforeRendering` is called every time._ .. Of course, you're calling `invalidate()` every time telling the framework to rerender, which isn't a public method btw. Please don't encourage readers to use non-public methods.

Answer (score 6):

For a modern SAPUI5 fiori-style application involving a `Component` and associated `routing` you could always attach a method to your view that would be called whenever there is a match with the supplied route pattern for that view. This route was historically supplied in the `metadata` of the `Component` class but since `v1.30` it's declared in the `manifest.json` file.

In the `onInit` method of your view, you can do:

```
onInit: function() {
    this._oRouter = this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter();
    this._oRouter.getRoute("yourRouteForThisView").attachPatternMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);
}
```

So you have the `_onObjectMatched` method that would be called every time you are on the view. Here you could place all your code here that should execute before your view is rendered.

```
_onObjectMatched: function(oEvent) {
    var oArgs = oEvent.getParameter("arguments");
    //If any values were passed in the URL then those will be available in oArgs
    //Do other stuff here
}
```

You can also use this for your landing page. The first view usually has an empty string `""` as its route pattern in the `manifest`.

Answer (score 4):

Another pattern is as below (with thanks to Matbtt)

```
onInit : function () {

    //...other code

    var router = this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter();
    var target = router.getTarget("<your route target name>");
    target.attachDisplay(this.onDisplay, this);
},

/** Fires evey time view is displayed.
 *
 * @param oEvent
 */
onDisplay: function(oEvent) {

    console.log('refreshData')
    this._refreshData()
},
```

The onDisplay function is fired each time the view is displayed. In my own small experience the on-render events get fired more frequently than one would initially assume.

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed the issue with `onBeforeShow`.Thanks jason for your efforts.

Comment: I´m using `onBeforeShow` for that case, too. You can see my answer regarding onBeforeShow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25140447/1969374).

Comment: @Papu Please accept this answer to help future readers. The current accepted answer has many flaws (outdated, suggesting to use non-public method, forcing view to rerender)