# How execute code every time that I view a page

Tags: sapui5

I'm searching the mode to execute a code (in my case the retrieve of data to visualize from server) every time I view a page (every time the page is called by `splitApp.toDetail` or `splitApp.backDetail`). How can i do it?

P.S. The `onBeforeRendering` and `onAfterRendering` execute only the first time.

Comment: _> The `onBeforeRendering` and `onAfterRendering` execute only the first time_ --> See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55099341/5846045

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a solution for you. There is a event called `routeMatched` when navigation is triggered every time. You can attach the event in the detail page.

```js
 onInit : function () {
    this._oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
    this._oRouter.attachRouteMatched(this.handleRouteMatched, this);
},

handleRouteMatched : function (evt) {
    //Check whether is the detail page is matched.
    if (evt.getParameter("name") !== "detail") {
        return;
    //You code here to run every time when your detail page is called.
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I´m using `onBeforeShow` in my target views for that.

```
onBeforeShow : function(evt) {
    // gets called everytime the user 
    // navigates to this view
},
```

This is a function which is fired **by** a [NavContainer](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.NavContainer.html) on its children in case of navigation. It´s documented in the [NavContainerChild](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.NavContainerChild.html).

Comment: Did you insert `onBeforeShow` in your target view. Means in the view that is targeted in `splitApp.toDetail(<view>)`?

Comment: yes, i replace `onBeforeRendering` with `onBeforeShow`. Now the code is never executed

Comment: Ok I tried it again and it works. In [this page](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/guide/5d13fd472e5b432b92848b7e46f6b648.html) it´s described to manually subscribe to this event. You could try this otherwise you can show us some more code (split app, views).

Comment: but on your application runs without registers for `beforeShow` event?
I only replace `onBeforeRendering` with `onBeforeShow`but not register a view by
`this.addEventDelegate({
    onBeforeShow: function(evt) {...`

Comment: Yes in my case it works without registering `onBeforeShow`. All my views simply provide `onBeforeShow` like `createContent`. [This thread](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3459136) on SCN is about events like `onBeforeShow`. Since you are using splitApp it should call `onBeforeShow` and related events for you. But let´s see some of your code to investigate it. You can simply edit and extend your question.

Comment: I register into onInit... it work...

`//INIT
 onInit: function() {
  
  //to register for beforeShow event
   this.getView().addEventDelegate({  
             // not added the controller as delegate to avoid controller functions with similar names as the events  
             onBeforeShow : jQuery.proxy(function(evt) {  
                       this.onBeforeShow(evt);  
             }, this)  
   });  
  
  
 },
 
 
 onBeforeShow : function(evt) {  
        alert("onBeforeShow"); 
 },`

Comment: Very interesting. I don´t know why you explicitly have to register for the events but glad to see that it works now.

Comment: Is it possible to get url parameters when inside onBeforeShow method?

Answer (score 5):

If routing is used, another version of Allen's code:

```
 onInit : function () {
   this._oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
   this._oRouter.getRoute("detail").attachMatched(this.handleRouteMatched, this);
},

  handleRouteMatched : function (evt) {
    //You code here to run every time when your detail page is called.
  }
```