# Error when setting model to the view in onBeforeShow

Tags: sapui5

I try to set a model to a view in onBeforeShow hook after I navigate to that view (using Router).

Here is my relevant view code part:

```js
<Table items="{path:'model>/'}">
    <columns>
        <!-- columns definition here -->
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <Text text="{model>property1}"/>
                <Text text="{model>property2}"/>
                <Text text="{model>property3}"/>
                <Text text="{model>property4}"/>
                <Text text="{model>property5}"/>
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

Then, in onBeforeShow:

```js
var oData = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("modelSource");
this.getView().setModel(oData, "model");
```

`"modelSource"` is defined in the previous view.

When executing the model set line, I get the following error:

> TypeError: e.bindList is not a function

Here is my onBeforeShow hook definition (credits to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139638/how-execute-code-every-time-that-i-view-a-page)):

```js
onInit: function() { 

    this.getView().addEventDelegate({ 
        onBeforeShow : jQuery.proxy(function(evt) { 
            this.onBeforeShow(evt); 
        }, this) 
    }); 
},
```

How to fix the issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not define the `modelSource` model correctly:

```js
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oData, "modelSource");
```

Defining it correctly:

```js
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData), "modelSource");
```

fixed the error.